# Как убрать кнопку разворачивания окна приложения на полный экран?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно удалить кнопку full size [image: Кнопка]

Приложение Windows forms (.NET framework)

Comment: `this.MaximizeBox = false;`

Comment: Спасибо! Щас попробую

Comment: Но я ее только деактивировал возможно ее скрыть полностью?

Comment: Только полностью переопределив шаблон отрисовки окна (но я бы не советовал этим заниматься). Хотя кнопка может быть убрана если вы и сворачивание тоже уберете `this.MinimizeBox = false;`.